# MIT app inventor 2 on exporting aia file

Tags: android

I am new in MIT app inventor. Recently I faced a problem when I exported my .aia file to QR code.

The errors given by the system:

[image: the errors given by the system]

My code:

[image: My code]

This is a homework problem.

Comment: I suppose this is one example of code that needs to be supplied as an image! However it is out of focus, even when viewed full size - can you supply a larger version?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I suspect we would need to see `begin.yail`, is that a text file? If so, please add it to your question, and supply it as text in a formatted block, rather than an image.

Answer (score 0):

If you're connecting via wireless to a mobile device, it is highly likely that your aia is too big for your device to handle. To test this, create a very small app with one simple command (like playing a sound) and try to connect. If it connects, chances are your aia is too big.

Also, as far as getting answers goes, unfortunately you just have to play the waiting game/learn to exercise patience.